# Java training course random number example generating build failed using bound

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Java SDK version:  1.8.0_291
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA Edu 2021.1
Runtime: 11.0.10+9-b1341.41 amd64

I've the sad misfortune of needing a certification in Java.  I'm taking Udemy course for 1Z0-808. The example code calls for the following to illustrate generating a random number from, I presume, 1 to 5.

```
package academy.learnprogramming;
import java.util.Random;

/**...*/

public class ImportExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        System.out.println(random.nextInt(bound:5));

    }
}
```

[image: Instructor_Screen]

[image: My Screen]

*bound* did not auto-fill for me.  I am certain I have everything he asked me to set up.  I'm attempting to search for references to this, but I'm coming up short - so here I am, ready for some Stackoverflow tough love to help me out.

I'm sending this stack question to the instructors as well.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: just remove `bound:` from the function. what you see in the image is a feature of IntelliJ, `bound:` is not actually written by the coder, rather IntelliJ has put it there just to make code more readable. That's not the part of your actual code.

Comment: Thanks.  I was been dumb there and not paying attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bound:` is just a hint, just code like this;

```
System.out.println(random.nextInt(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want random number between `min` to `max` you can create function :

```
package main;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static int randomInt(int min, int max) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return min + rand.nextInt(max);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(randomInt(0, 5));
    }
}
```

and call if need.

Comment: should be `rand.nextInt(max - min)`